# Is it possible to use a ppp connection rather than a veth to connect docker and host?

Tags: docker, point-to-point-protocol

I know a veth pair can be created to used communicate between docker container and host:

```sh
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1 netns test
```

But I just want to known if there a simple way to make the vitual ethernet to a ppp interface?

Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) Docker already creates veth-pairs, no need to make your own. (2) You can share a pty and run pppd both on the host and in the container, but it's very much not "simple", and it doesn't use a veth.

Comment: @dirkt it sounds very great, thank you very much. Would you please give some clues to google the ppp over pty?